# text not editable onkeydown event

Tags: javascript, event-handling, onkeydown

On the keydown event, the text which is in center if the textbox is not editable. When I write anything in textbox, it writes at the right most, not at the position where I'm trying to write. Also, I have written a function to teake characters in only caps but the last letter written doesn't change in caps except if we are changing textbox via tab.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "javascript:return descrip(this.value)");
    }
```

In the ASPx source, it describes the function I have written:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    <!--
    function descrip(text)
    {document.form1.TextBox1.value=text.toUpperCase();

    }
   //-->
 </script>
```

Comment: you need to include more tags relevant to your question in order to get the correct and quick answer otherwise people wont see the question you asked or it's likely to be shown to less people

Answer (score 0):

`this.value` is not changed yet (@ the onkeydown event)

So just change it to:

```
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "descrip(this.value)");
```

**onkeyup** is fired after the value is updated. 
**return** is not needed, because there's nothing to cancel/return.
**javascript:** is not needed, onkeyup expects javascript code.